# All outputs from function are the same

Tags: python, list, function, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a function to read VCF files

```
def readVCF(VCF):
    VCF = VCF.readlines()
    header = [] 
    data = []
    for line in VCF:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            header.append(line) 
        else:
            data.append(line)
    VCF_contents =[]  
    for line in data:
        VCF_contents.extend(line.strip().split('\t'))
    for i in range(0, len(VCF_contents), 10): 
        lines.append(VCF_contents[i : i+10])
```

The function works as I want it to, but problems start when I use it more than once.

I want to use this function multiple times, on different files, and the use the outputs from all these different files simultaneously. I have been using the function like this:

```
VCF = open("frogs.txt", 'r')
lines = []
readVCF(VCF)
frogs = lines
VCF.close

VCF = open("rabbits.txt.", 'r')
readVCF(VCF)
rabbits = lines
VCF.close

VCF = open("lizards.txt", 'r')
readVCF(VCF)
lizards = lines
VCF.close
```

The problem is that, all my outputs are the same, and all have the output that comes from `frogs.txt`, the first file I used the function for. How can reuse this function without getting the same values?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so what is supposed to be in `lines`?

Comment: @OferSadan apologies, it is now irrelevant as I have understood my issue anyway.

Comment: You need to clear out the contents of the `lines` list your function is using either before calling it, with `lines = []` or at the beginning of the function with a `lines[:] = []` statement.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to use a dedicated VCF library like e.g. [`PyVCF`](https://pypi.org/project/PyVCF/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, you want to add:

```
lines = []
```

inside your function at the beginning and:

```
return lines
```

at the end of your function, and call it like e.g.:

```
VCF = open("frogs.txt", 'r')
frogs = readVCF(VCF)
VCF.close()
```

or alternatively (probably better):

```
with open("frogs.txt", 'r') as VCF:
    frogs = readVCF(VCF)
```